# Javascript Array sort

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I'm learning to code and I need some help please. I'm making a game when the player has to guess a colour. I need help in the case that the player writes an String that is not in the array. I have been trying to find a solution but I couldn't.

**The codes is here:**

```
<script>

    var guess_input;
    var target_index;
    var target;
    var color = ["cyan", "magenta", "green", "blue", "red"];
    var finished = false;
    var count = 0;
    function do_game() {
        var target_index = Math.random() * color.length;
        var target_index = Math.floor(target_index);
        var target = color[target_index];
        alert(target);

        while(!finished) {
            var guess_input = prompt("I am thinking one of these colors: " + "\n\n" + color.sort() + "\n\n" + "What color am I thinking of?");
            count++;
            alert(guess_input);
            var finished = check_guess();
        }
        function check_guess()  {   
            //HERE I NEED A CODE IN THE CASE THAT
            //THE PLAYER WRITE AN STRING THAT IS
            //NOT IN THE ARRAY OF COLOURS

            if (target > guess_input) {
                alert("Your color is lower");
                return false;
            }
            if (target < guess_input) {
                alert("Your color is higher")
                return false; 
            }
            if (target===guess_input) {
                myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background=target;
                alert("Congratulations, you have guessed, it took you " + count + "  times")
                return true;
            }   
        }       
    }   

</script>
```

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating the task a lot

Comment: thanks, that was really helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

besides the fact that your code crashed my tab, here is some code you can have.

```
    var guess_input;
    var target_index;
    var target;
    var color = ["cyan", "magenta", "green", "blue", "red"];
    var finished = false;
    var count = 0;
    function do_game() {
        var target_index = Math.random() * color.length;
        var target_index = Math.floor(target_index);
        var target = color[target_index];
        alert(target);

        while(!finished) {
            var guess_input = prompt("I am thinking one of these colors: " + "\n\n" + color.sort() + "\n\n" + "What color am I thinking of?");
            count++;
            alert(guess_input);
            var finished = check_guess();
        }
        function check_guess()  {   
            //HERE I NEED A CODE IN THE CASE THAT
            //THE PLAYER WRITE AN STRING THAT IS
            //NOT IN THE ARRAY OF COLOURS

            if(color.indexOf(guess_input) == -1){
                alert("You guessed wrong chumley!");
            }

            if (target > guess_input) {
                alert("Your color is lower");
                return false;
            }
            if (target < guess_input) {
                alert("Your color is higher")
                return false; 
            }
            if (target===guess_input) {
                myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background=target;
                alert("Congratulations, you have guessed, it took you " + count + "  times")
                return true;
            }   
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the user input is one of your color with the method indexOf().
Ex:

```
if(color.indexOf("yellow") == -1){
 alert('error');
}
```

Comment: ok, got it. But that it is just for one specific colour ("yellow"). I would like to check the hole array. Is that make sense?

Comment: no, it is not specific. The point of indexOf is that it checks the whole array for a value. If it doesn't find the value, it returns -1.